# Irregular Border Box With CSS

Tags: html, css, box

Does any body knows how to draw this irregular border in CSS?[image: Irregular Box]

I have tried something like this but it doesn't gives me irregular lines.

```
    .IrregularBox {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: 2px #000 solid ;
  border-radius: 50% / 10%;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: .1em;
}
.IrregularBox:before {
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  right: -5%;
  left: -5%;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 5% / 50%;
}
```